# Parsing Erlang data to Python dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, erlang

I have an erlang script from which I would like to get some data and store it in python dictionary.
It is easy to parse the script to get string like this:

```
    {userdata,
     [{tags,
       [#dt{number=111},
        #mp{id='X23.W'}]},
      {log,
       'LG22'},
      {instruction,
       "String that can contain characters like -, _ or numbers"}
     ]
    }.
```

desired result:

```
userdata = {"tags": {"dt": {"number": 111}, "mp": {"id": "X23.W"}},
            "log": "LG22",
            "instruction": "String that can contain characters like -, _ or numbers"}
# "#" mark for data in "tags" is not required in this structure. 
# Also value for "tags" can be any iterable structure: tuple, list or dictionary.
```

But I am not sure how to transfer this data into a python dictionary. My first idea was to use `json.loads` but it requires many modifications (putting words into quotes marks, replacing "," with ":" and many more).

Moreover, keys in userdata are not limited to some pool. In this case, there are 'tags', 'log' and 'instruction', but there can be many more eg. 'slogan', 'ids', etc.
Also, I am not sure about the order. I assume that the keys can appear in random order.

My code (it is not working for `id='X23.W'` so I removed '.' from input):

```
import re
import json
in_ = """{userdata, [{tags, [#dt{number=111}, #mp{id='X23W'}]}, {log, 'LG22'}, {instruction, "String that can contain characters like -, _ or numbers"}]}"""

buff = in_.replace("{userdata, [", "")[:-2]

re_helper = re.compile(r"(#\w+)")
buff = re_helper.sub(r'\1:', buff)

partition = buff.partition("instruction")
section_to_replace = partition[0]
replacer = re.compile(r"(\w+)")
match = replacer.sub(r'"\1"', section_to_replace)
buff = ''.join([match, '"instruction"', partition[2]])
buff = buff.replace("#", "")
buff = buff.replace('",', '":')

buff = buff.replace("}, {", "}, \n{")
buff = buff.replace("=", ":")
buff = buff.replace("'", "")
temp = buff.split("\n")
userdata = {}
buff = temp[0][:-2]
buff = buff.replace("[", "{")
buff = buff.replace("]", "}")

userdata .update(json.loads(buff))
for i, v in enumerate(temp[1:]):
    v = v.strip()
    if v.endswith(","):
        v = v[:-1]
    userdata .update(json.loads(v))

print(userdata)
```

Output:

```
{'tags': {'dt': {'number': '111'}, 'mp': {'id': 'X23W'}}, 'instruction': 'String that can contain characters like -, _ or numbers', 'log': 'LG22'}
```

Comment: your desired result is not valid python.

Comment: Cannot you just use [tag:erlang] to spit out the result in the form that can be understood by [tag:python]? Like _JSON_?

Comment: "It is easy to parse the script to get string like this" what do you mean, exactly, by "parse the script?" Like, the source code?

Comment: @Wombatz Oh yes! You are right! Sorry for that mistake! value for `tags` should be dictionary then: `"tags": {"dt": {"number": 111}, "mp": {"id": "X23.W"}}`

@AlekseiMatiushkin I don't want to use erlang in my application.

@juanpa.arrivillaga Yes exactly. My input is some code written in erlang. I am parsing ".erl" file to get data from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import json
import re
in_ = """{userdata, [{tags, [#dt{number=111}, #mp{id='X23.W'}]}, {log, 'LG22'}, {instruction, "String that can contain characters like -, _ or numbers"}]}"""


qouted_headers = re.sub(r"\{(\w+),", r'{"\1":', in_)
changed_hashed_list_to_dict = re.sub(r"\[(#.*?)\]", r'{\1}', qouted_headers)

hashed_variables = re.sub(r'#(\w+)', r'"\1":', changed_hashed_list_to_dict)
equality_signes_replaced_and_quoted = re.sub(r'{(\w+)=', r'{"\1":', hashed_variables)
replace_single_qoutes = equality_signes_replaced_and_quoted.replace('\'', '"')

result = json.loads(replace_single_qoutes)
print(result)
```

Produces:

```
{'userdata': [{'tags': {'dt': {'number': 111}, 'mp': {'id': 'X23.W'}}}, {'log': 'LG22'}, {'instruction': 'String that can contain characters like -, _ or numbers'}]}
```

Comment: I didn't notice you were already using regex group replacement. I focused mainly on string replacement, sorry for that, removed useless reference from answer. Anyway glad I helped.